# Get a integer if there are no significant digits after decimal or get a float if there are significant digits after decimal in python

Tags: python, operators, division, median, integer-division

I was recently doing a question on geeks for geeks website where they required median of two sorted arrays, but they are asking answer to be a int if there are no digits after decimals or a float if there are digits after decimals. For example when giving median of even number arrays, we usually divide middle elements with two, so if middle elements are `2` and `4` then after division answer should be `3`, or if elements are `3` and `4` answer should be `3.5`. But if we use `/` operator in python it will return division of `2` and `4` as `3.0`, and if we use `//` operator it will return division of `3` and `4` as `3` instead of `3.5`. Is there any way to get around this instead of checking divisibility by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this potentially. Do the division as normal and then apply the following:

```
if int(x) == x: # will be true if x=5.0 but not if x = 5.5
  x = int(x)
```